# Gradle project sync failed in importing another module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on an android app where I tried importing a different module(another project), also tried adding the dependencies of the second module to the first module by going to project structure. But it says Gradle project sync failed and I've posted the screenshots down below.

**1st module build gradle**
compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.*****.*****"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

**2nd module build gradle**
 compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.*****.*****"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

[Screenshots of output-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljEKL.png)
[Screenshots of output-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhCDD.png)

Please help me out!

Comment: post your gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
Build > Clean Project
```

then

```
Build> Rebuild Project
```